# How to increment session variable on for submit

Tags: php, session-variables

I have form to add employess to database. I have to count how many employess were added during one session and display it somewhere on the screen.

Right now my form_validation.php looks like this:

```
<?php
 session_start();

 if(formValidationIsCorrect){
   $_SESSION['counter']++;
   header("location:pageWithFormDetails.php);
 }
```

in `pageWithFormDetails.php` I have to display employee information from form (name, age, etc.), and how many employess were added during this session.

My problem is, that when on `pageWithFormDetails.php` 
I do

`<?php echo $_SESSION['counter']; ?>` it always displays **1**, even If i refill form few times. I guess everytime I complete form, my `counter` variable is reset, and then incremented by **1**. Is there a way not to reset this variable every time I complete form, and validate it?

Comment: because you header redirects whenever formvalidation returns true. in your case it returns true on first hit and  redirect you. you need put header after if condition

Answer (score 0):

You need to use database input and then output. When you are attempting to $_SESSION ++. There you can use ++ in db variable then -1 when you are destroying the session. That's how I did this when I needed similar type of thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code snippet and change your code accordingly

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
  array_key_exists('counter', $_SESSION) ? $_SESSION['counter']++ : ($_SESSION['counter'] =1);
  echo $_SESSION['counter'];
}
?>
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```